# How to call remove when I have a hash of resources in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service like bellow, how is it possible to call "admins remove" from controller? I know, how to call it without user or admin "scope" (`promToRemove.$remove()`) but in this situation I am despairing. I also know, how to successfully call get.

```
angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        user: $resource('users/:userId', { userId: '@_id' },
            { get: { method: 'GET' }},
            { update: { method: 'PUT' }}
        ),
        admin: $resource('admin/users/:userId', { userId: '@_id' },
            { get: { method: 'GET' }},
            { update: { method: 'PUT' }},
            { remove: { method: 'DELETE' }}
        )
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to issue a DELETE command to that API endpoint, try calling the $delete method on that object.

userIWantToDelete.$delete(function() {});

But It will need to have the _id property.

Comment: This will make a request on `http://localhost:3000/admin/users?_id=552bb687ee568414260b4ff8` but I need `http://localhost:3000/admin/users/552bb687ee568414260b4ff8`. How to do that?